# Get results as simple value from Laravel query builder

Tags: laravel

I get the output of the values as following in the postman.
[{"currentVersion":1.1}]

How can i get output in simple form as: 1.1

```
$currentVersion = DB::table('app_Version')
    ->select('currentVersion')
    ->get();
echo $currentVersion
```

How can i get output in simple form as:
1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do:

```
echo $currentVersion[0]->currentVersion;
```

However, if you know you'll always have one record, you could simplify this a bit with:

```
$result = DB::table('app_Version')->first(['currentVersion']);
echo $result->currentVersion;
```